# Make User Role a Filter

Tags: customization

I have a backend which I'm trying to edit.

Basically it says:
If (any) user is logged in, show some records, else show nothing.

I'd like to limit this to a certain role named "Administrator", like i.e. if user is logged in AND user role = administrator then display records

Can anyone help me with this?

### Here's what I have:

```
<div class="proposals-list row">
    <div class="columns large-12">

    <?php hrb_before_post_section( HRB_PROJECTS_PTYPE, 'proposals' ); ?>

    <?php if ( ! empty( $proposals ) && is_user_logged_in() ): ?>

        <?php foreach( $proposals as $proposal ): ?>

            <?php appthemes_load_template( 'content-proposal.php', array( 'proposal' => $proposal ) ); ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php elseif ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

        <h5 class="no-results"><?php echo __( 'No Proposals Yet.', APP_TD ) . ( ( current_user_can( 'add_bid', get_the_ID() ) ? ' ' . sprintf( __( '<a href="%s">Apply to Project.</a>', APP_TD ), get_the_hrb_apply_to_url() ) : '' ) ); ?></h5>

    <?php else: ?>

        <h5 class="no-results"><?php echo sprintf( __( 'Please <a href="%s">login</a> to view this project proposals.', APP_TD ), wp_login_url( get_permalink() . '#proposals' ) ); ?></h5>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php hrb_after_post_section( HRB_PROJECTS_PTYPE, 'proposals' ); ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `is_user_logged_in()` with `is_super_admin()`.